# Can't switch to my nvidia graphics card and i am not sure if system detects it

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I looked up many similar questions in this and other sites for really long time; but couldn't find any solutions. I have a laptop with GeForce 840M and cant get it work. I am using Intel's graphics card as I can understand. I am new to Ubuntu so please answer accordingly. From looking at different questions maybe these information helps to find a solution.

With this command I can't see nvidia device; and when i click about this computer it also writes Intel.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

But with this command: lspci -v

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 1116
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

You can see it.

I have performance issues with games and some of them are not playable at all due to this. Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First install the NVIDIA drivers and NVIDIA Optimus to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

You can see whether the NVIDIA card is in use (Kernel driver in use: nvidia) with this command :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output reads like this :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Open NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles and switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but it doesnt work. When i try to use xserver settings for switching it doesnt let me. I enter my password as it asks and then i get an an error without any text. Although this was a solution i tried before as; i searched many answers around web, i tried again and nope still doesnt work.